# How to fix file access when using a sub-directory?

Tags: csv, go, directory

Which way Go does handle read access to directories and files?

I want to read a folder, search for csv files and save the content per csv file in order to send the content via http request.

Here's my code:

```
func GetFileContent(fileName string) ([][]string, error) {
  file, err := os.Open(fileName)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("There was an error:", err)
    return nil, err
  }

  defer file.Close()
  reader := csv.NewReader(file)
  reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1
  csvFileContent, err := reader.ReadAll()
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("There was an error:", err)
    return nil, err
  }
  return csvFileContent, nil
}

func GetFiles(importPath string, fileExtension string) ([]string, error) {

  var result []string

  directory, err := os.Open(importPath)
  if err != nil {
    return result, err
  }
  defer directory.Close()

  files, err := directory.Readdir(-1)
  if err != nil {
    return result, err
  }

  for _, file := range files {
    if file.Mode().IsRegular() {
      if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == "." + fileExtension {
        log.Println("Import Files: ", file.Name())
        result = append(result, file.Name())
      }
    }
  }
  if len(result) == 0 {
    log.Println("No import files of type " + fileExtension + " found.")
    log.Println("Import skipped.")
  }
  return result, nil
}
```

> Error: open : no such file or directory

appears when I do not use the root folder / working directory of my application but another (parent) folder? It works as long as I use ./ as source folder.

Comment: How exactly are you running this?

Comment: no, I mean are you running the compiled binary, or `go run`? Are you using absolute paths, or relative paths?

Comment: Actually I have tried both with relative paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FileInfo.Name](http://godoc.org/os#FileInfo.Name) returns the base name of the file. You need to [join](http://godoc.org/path/filepath#Join) the directory name with the base name to get a file path.

Change this line in GetFiles

```
result = append(result, file.Name())
```

to

```
result = append(result, filepath.Join(importPath, file.Name()))
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you might consider using the higher-level [filepath.Glob()](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) instead:

```
files, err := filepath.Glob(filepath.Join(importPath, "*.csv"))
```

Comment: I finally decided to use Glob in my last script version. When I came to the point where I needed the filename I used strip + separator to get rid of the path and slash. Thanks for this!